# Select child from expandablelistview by code

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i Select child from expandablelistview by code ?

I have id of this child from another activity , this id comes from cursor from another activity .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selectChild function:

http://www.androidjavadoc.com/m5-rc15/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html#setSelectedChild(int,%20int,%20boolean)

An example:

```
listView.setSelectedChild(1, 1, true);
```

Comment: i do that at oncreate() but , application crash with this error Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: The nullPointerException is caused because listView is null...
Check if you have just created it and if not use thic code when the list view exists and the adapter is set.

Comment: OK , where can i set it ? i want to select item on activity create .

Comment: post your onCreate method and i can indicate the best place to setSelected

Answer (score 0):

```
 View v = myExpandableListView.findViewById(id);
 v.setSelected(true);
```